# Flutter - InputDatePickerFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a text field that will get the date in the input field. I'm using InputDatePickerFormField widget. The issue I'm finding that it does not show error when the date is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
class _BirthDay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __BirthDayState createState() => __BirthDayState();
}

class __BirthDayState extends State<_BirthDay> {
  DateTime? selectedDate;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firstDate = DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 120);
    final lastDate = DateTime.now();

    return InputDatePickerFormField(
      firstDate: firstDate,
      lastDate: lastDate,
      fieldLabelText: '${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.dateOfBirth}',
      errorFormatText: '${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.dateOfBirthInvalid}',
      errorInvalidText: '${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.dateOfBirthInvalid}',
      onDateSubmitted: (date) {
        print(date);
        setState(() {
          selectedDate = date;
        });
      },
      onDateSaved: (date) {
        print(date);
        setState(() {
          selectedDate = date;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: make Form widget as parent of InputDatePickerFormField and using formkey that is  formKey.currentState.validate(); on any unclick event you will get error regarding your input data

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can add a checker on your Text fields is by setting the fields as children of a [Form](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html). Using this, you'll be able to validate the values on your fields once submitted.

```dart
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

...

Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: InputDatePickerFormField(...),
)
```

Then you can run a check using `_formKey.currentState!.validate())`. Trigger this validation on any `onClick` or `onPressed` event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the form to see the validations errors

```
_formKey2.currentState.save();
```

You can call it on the submit button